# Did this Game of Thrones character cause the previous king to go mad?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Spoiler alert! If you haven't seen 6th season episodes, you might want to avoid reading any further.

> We know (or strongly suspect) that Bran Stark caused Wyllis/Hodor to
>  become mentally ill by warging into him back in time.
>  Could the Three-Eyed-Raven have warged into (or spoken into the mind
>  of) the Mad King Aerys? He could have tried to warn Aerys about the
>  white walkers and encouraged him to burn the white walkers. This led
>  to Aerys going insane and saying "burn them all".

Is there anything from the books which help answer that question?

Comment: Whomever flagged this as "primarily opinion-based" why? They are asking if it is addressed in the books.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Thanks. That's exactly my request. Is there any information in the books that supports or disproves what I wrote?

Comment: @MeatTrademark the Hodor scene hasn't happened in the books yet, and it's difficult to prove a negative. I didn't flag, however I'm assuming those who did viewed this as a 'future works' situation.  The questions provided are very detailed, and I up voted both, however they still are opinions until we see (in the show or books) Bran warg into the mad king or both the books and show ends without seeing this.

Comment: Are the reopen votes here because this question got answered in new GoT material? I'm happy to add my reopen vote if that's what happened but since there aren't any comments claiming it did and I don't watch GoT...

Comment: If the question is "do the books show x" and the books do not, that's an answer isn't it? If it's fuzzy, comment that. The OP was **not asking for opinions.** "Is there anything from the books which help answer that question?" If not, say so.

Comment: @Ixrec no new GoT material.

Comment: @MeatTrademark the answer to the objective question is no the books don't explicitly show anything to help answer this. But this is a book series that's been in progress for 20 years, there's been a lot of speculation and reading into small details in that time.  There are details that people use to argue both sides of this, and that's an opinion based answer.

Comment: @MeatTrademark by the way. If you're responding to someone please use the @ username. I don't always look back at answers I've commented on without notifications, I just happened to look at this one.

Comment: @kuhl I was not addressing anyone in particular, I was commenting on the closed status.

Comment: @kuhl I was asking more about already published books, not future ones. Perhaps GRRM left a hint that the 3 Eyed Raven had some connection with the Mad King, or recommended to the Mad King to use Wild Fire. (e.g. - Does any book hint that Wild Fire is useful against White Walkers?)

Comment: Isn't Bran unique, even beyond the Max Von Sydow three-eyed raven, in his ability to warg into a human?  I got the impression that even the (pre-Bran) three-eyed raven couldn't do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No there is no such evidence in the books or any mention of it.**

Why, you ask? Because:

### Fire's ineffectiveness against Others

Melisandre said:

> "Necromancy animates these wights, yet they are still only dead flesh.
>   Steel and fire will serve for them. The ones you call the Others are
>   something more."

This implies that Others can't be killed by normal fire and steel.

Also in [Battle of the Fist of First Men](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fight_at_the_Fist), we saw that fire arrows did not stop the onslaught of the others and their thralls.

This proves that others are immune to ordinary fire and thus it makes no sense for Three Eyed Raven to try and warn the mad king to the danger and to use ordinary fire against them. Granted, Wildfire burns hotter than ordinary fire but it is no magical fire.

Some might point out that Pyromancers do mention that appearance of dragons could result in increased production of Wildfire in prelude to battle of Blackwater bay but that does not prove Wildfire is magical. If it were magical, art of producing wildfire should have died when last dragon died in reign of Aegon III. Dragons might act as catalyst to production of Wildfire but the product remains chemical in nature, not magical.

### Three Eyed Raven's preferred means of Communication

When Three eyed Raven wanted to communicate something, he uses dreams and even messengers as we saw in case of Bran when he used to appear in his dreams and even sent the Reed Siblings to get him to North. He did not "warg" into Bran and make him come beyond the wall.

### Skin Changers code of Ethics beyond the wall

From what we know from Wildlings, Skinchangers have a code of honor according to [which warging into another human is considered horrible and abomination](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Haggon) if used to manipulate the other person.

### Targaryen Inbreeding and madness

[Targaryen madness](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Targaryen_madness) is something which can be attributed to centuries of incest and inbreeding. Aerys's grandfather, [Aegon V](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_V_Targaryen) detested incest and tried to marry his children to other houses. Two of them, [Jaehaerys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaerys_II_Targaryen) and [Shaera](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Shaera_Targaryen) however secretly married each other and Aegon was forced to accept that. Jaehaerys and Shaera later had Aerys (insane) and Rhaella (sane), who were married to each other. Results were Rhaegar (sane), Viserys (Insane), Daenerys (Sane). Aegon V himself had a mad brother, [Aerion the Monstrous](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aerion_Targaryen), who thought drinking wildfire would make him a dragon.

Historical mad Targaryens include:

1. [King Maegor the Cruel](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maegor_I_Targaryen)
2. [King Baelor the Blessed](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Baelor_I_Targaryen)
3. [Prince Rhaegel](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaegel_Targaryen)
4. [Prince Aerion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aerion_Targaryen)
5. [King Aerys II the Mad](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aerys_II_Targaryen)
6. [Prince Viserys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Viserys_Targaryen)

No one warged into five of the six even if we assume Aerys went mad because of that, they still were insane.

### Who is Three eyed raven?

In Books, it is a [very popular theory](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/2hcg3q/spoilers_adwd_who_is_bloodraven/) that three eyed raven is a Targaryen himself, [Brynden Bloodraven](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brynden_Rivers), son of King Aegon IV and uncle to Maester Aemon. He killed his [half-brother](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daemon_I_Blackfyre) and [nephews](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Blackfyre_Rebellion) to protect Targaryen dynasty in Blackfyre rebellions. He was later sent to the wall for another such act done to protect the Targaryen dynasty from Blackfyres. Why would he sow seeds to destroy it by taking the risk of making Aerys mad even if we discard the evidence that Aerys was inbred enough to go mad anyways?

Three eyed raven said about changing course of events:

> "I have my own ghosts, Bran. A brother that I loved ([Daemon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daemon_I_Blackfyre) or [Daeron](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daeron_II_Targaryen)), a
>   brother that I hated ([Aegor](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegor_Rivers)), a woman that I desired ([Shiera](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Shiera_Seastar)). Through
>   the trees, I see them still, but no word of mine has ever reached
>   them. The past remains the past. We can learn from it, but we cannot
>   change it."

### Aerys's Obsession with fire and dragons

Aerys was obsessed with fire [long before](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aerys_II_Targaryen#Year_of_the_False_Spring) Others ever reappeared after the long night. According to Jaime, Aerys hoped to rise again as a dragon from ashes, another one of Targaryen madnesses. Aerion too thought that drinking wildfire would make him rise as a dragon. His order to burn the city was simply given to take final revenge from Robert as a Dragon. Jaime made sure that did not happen by cutting his throat.

From ASOS Jaime V, Jaime recalling Aerys's order to burn the city:

> Aerys meant to have the greatest funeral pyre of them all. Though if
>   truth be told, I do not believe he truly expected to die. Like Aerion
>   Brightfire before him, Aerys thought the fire would transform him...
>   that he would rise again, reborn as a dragon, and turn all his enemies
>   to ash.

Comment: I think in the book the alchemist claim wildfire is magical (but the maesters deny this). Hallyne did admit to Tyrion he didn't understand how suddenly their production of the stuff went through the roof at the same time dragons came back into the world and obsidian candles started burning.

Comment: That did happen. The production was increased with return of the dragons which however does not imply that the substance itself was magical seeing as most of the things pyromancers did were mere tricks which were noted by Red priests as well. Somethings, in this case dragons, can act as catalyst to a chemical process but I believe the outcome remains chemical

Comment: Anyhow, we do not know if wildfire has any different impact on others than ordinary fire as it has never been employed against them yet. Sorry about the delay, SO went offline.

Comment: The pyromancers stated their spells become much more effective lately. "Spell" somewhat points to magic. I am not claiming that wildfire may or may not be effective against the Others, I am simply questioning the choice of words here.

Comment: @C.Koca In the same passage Tyrion notes that most of their "spells" are simple manufacturing procedures. Plus if it were magic, Wildfire should have gone extinct with last dragon when the magic went out.  Anyhow I have stated that we do not know if wildfire works against others.

Comment: @Aegon Not necessarily. Dragons were long gone, but smiths were able to reshape Valyrian steels with spells. Wildfire production efficiency is also related to the existence of dragons. I guess magic is not black or white, there are many shades of grey as well. Danerys was told that a fire rope climber (or something of this sort) performed much worse before the birth of dragons. But he did some magic. Dragons make magic stronger. Without dragons, magic may lose its potent in due time, however it doesn't necessarily become useless.

Comment: @C.Koca I have created [a question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129575/is-wildfire-magical-or-chemical) about this. Maybe you would like to share your thoughts there?

Answer (score 16):

[Targaryen Madness](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Targaryen_madness) isn't that uncommon that it needs a convoluted explanation. There's a line in the books about this:

> I am no maester to quote history at you, Your Grace. Swords have been my life, not books. But every child knows that the Targaryens have always danced too close to madness. Your father was not the first. King Jaehaerys once told me that madness and greatness are two sides of the same coin. Every time a new Targaryen is born, he said, the gods toss the coin in the air and the world holds its breath to see how it will land
> <sub>***-Ser Barristan to Daenerys From a Storm of Swords Chapter 71***</sub>

The Targaryens interbred their family lines too much that it often produced madness.

**Edit:** Also to specifically address the point about the "Burn them all", we have no indication that fire has any effect on the white walkers. Obsidian / Dragonglass and Valyrian steel can kill White Walkers. Fire can kill the Wights they resurrect.

Giving the Mad King instructions on how to kill the wights would be pointless as we saw previously the Nights King can almost instantly create more. If the raven would give instructions it would be to gather all dragon-steel swords and send them to the wall.

*Turn the blades north so to speak... Turn them to the Wall.... Turn to the Wall...Turn to t'wall....*

Jaime: "*What was that?*"

Comment: Who said that phrase about tossing a coin? Barristan Selmy?
And what the phrase "Turn to t'wall" sounds like, and to what could it transform?

Comment: Yeah it was Selmy to Daneries. I've updated the answer. The turn to t'wall? I was just joking. I couldn't quite get from "Burn them all" to "Turn to the Wall"

Comment: To be honest the whole thing doesn't work out timewise either. The king went mad and got stabbed by Jamie then about 15 years later (pretty much exactly Jon Snows age when the show starts) we see the very first white walker.

Comment: In the books, there is no indication that Night's King could raise armies of dead or that he was more than a man.

Comment: @MikeyMouse I suspect the White Walkers were around 15+ years before the story began. How long has Craster had his deal with the White Walkers? The walkers could have been around for decades, but in far fewer numbers until recently. The Three Eyed Raven could have seen them, guessed (foresaw?) what the walkers would do given enough time, and then he would decide to warn the king. But the very act of warning the king made the king turn mad.